# sending local wifi ssid and password to esp32 from android without configuration

Tags: java, android, esp32

I have an **esp32** which is going to read data from dht11 and since it might be in different local networks , I  initially want to find esp32 (connect to it) by android phone  and pass the ssid and password of local network to it. and after passing ssid and password ,  they both connect to the local network .
how can I achieve this especially if there is a way for android phone not disconnecting from the local network during passing the data to esp32 .
I have come a across some solutions like **wifi direct** or **auto connect** , but I'm not sure.

 any solutions and  recommendations and **sample code for esp32** would be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer : use smartConfig example with esp32 and use ESPTOUCH for android phone.
PS: although there are some other provisioning ways like : blfi and AP mode